# Bayes Rule Probability: What are the odds of something happening

Tags: bayesian, bayes-theorem

Assume that a disease has a prevalence of 0.3% in the population. A company had developed a diagnostic for this disease that is 97% reliable (meaning that it detects 97% of true cases) but has a false positive rate of 2%.

a) If a person is tested positive by the diagnostic test, what are the odds that the person has the disease (odds of A = probability of A / probability of not A)?

b) What is the probability that the person does not have the disease?

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: When you pose a question here, you should include your attempt to solve the problem and indicate where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the input. I usually write my answer approach when I post questions, but I literally have no idea how to do this (no stats background) which is why I was just asking for some insight on how to begin it. Once I work on it, I will update with my attempted answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although there are straightforward formulas for this kind of thing, you can often get a more intuitive feel for the situation by just drawing up a sample population.  Imagine you have $100000$ people (a hundred thousand).  Since $0.3$ percent of the population has the disease, it affects $300$ people.

Of those $300$ people, $97$ percent, or $291$ people, will test positive.  The other $9$ people with the disease will test negative.

Of the remaining $99700$ people, $2$ percent, or $1994$ people, will test positive.  The other $92706$ people without the disease will test negative.

Thus, of the $291+1994 = 2285$ people who test positive, only $291$ of them ($291/2285 = 0.127$, or $12.7$ percent) will actually have the disease.  The other $87.3$ percent will be false positives.

The formula, from Bayes's Rule, is

$$
P(B \mid A) = \frac{P(A \mid B)P(B)}{P(A \mid B)P(B)+P(A \mid \neg B)P(\neg B)}
$$

where $A = \text{tests positive}$ and $B = \text{has the disease}$, and the $\neg$ sign means "not."